# Get All customers from Magento using rest API

Tags: api, rest-api, wsdl, xmlrpc

I am trying to get all customers from Magento, but it giving me only first 10 records, i have searched a lot but did not see any post of comment which can solve my problem.

API user has admin rights and able to fetch results using Rest API.

if i have activated application for rest API then can i use wsdl as well or xml rpc please suggest.

Comment: Please post your code so that we can see what/how you are  trying to do.

Comment: i am following this link https://gmartinezgil.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/using-the-magento-rest-api-in-java-with-scribe/ and able to get the auth_token with key. but when i tried to get all customers by providing all parameters it is giving me only 10 customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on this [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html). and here is the explanation on it.

> You can define the limit of items returned in the response by passing the limit parameter. By default, 10 items are returned and the maximum number is 100 items. You can also define the page number by passing the page parameter. Example:

http://magentohost/api/rest/products?page=2&limit=20

Comment: how to get product with filter status=1 and visibility=4.?